# Is there a way to visit a shortened url and parse the extended version of that url? R, Python, JS/Node

Tags: javascript, python, r, node.js, python-requests

For example, if I visit a url like `tripadvisor.com/6887990`

The extended version of that url that appears in the browser becomes `https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Attraction_Review-g1121284-d6887990-Reviews-Koishidani_Shrine-Minamiyamashiro_mura_Soraku_gun_Kyoto_Prefecture_Kinki.html`

Is there a way to programmatically visit an entire list/vector/array of shortened urls and then store the extended urls in another list/vector/array?

Happy to approach any language that can accomplish this but preferably in R, Python or JS/Node

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IainShelvington I have a pre-defined and limited list of urls.

Comment: @IainShelvington That sounds like a great idea, i'm asking for a practical example of how this is accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.js, you can find out what the redirected URL is like this:

```
const got = require('got');

got('https://www.tripadvisor.com/6887990', {followRedirect: false}).then(r => {
    if (r.statusCode === 301 || response.statusCode === 302) {
        console.log(r.headers.location);    // this will be the redirect URL
    } else {
        console.log(`statusCode ${r.statusCode} was not a redirect`);
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And, then you could use that redirected URL to go fetch the actual content.  Or you can let the `got()` library follow the redirect for you automatically and just let it fetch the content for you.

```
got('https://www.tripadvisor.com/6887990').then(r => {
    console.log(r.body);            // this is the content of the redirected page
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

To run through an array of URLs, the safest way is to do them one at a time (to avoid rate limiting or DOS limiting):

```
async function run(listOfUrls) {
    let results = [];
    for (let url of listOfUrls) {
        let response = await got(url);
        if (response.statusCode === 301 || response.statusCode === 302) {
            results.push(response.headers.location);
        } else {
            results.push(url);
        }            
    }
    return results;
}

run(["https://somedomain.com/url1", "https://somedomain.com/url2", ...])
  .then(results => {
      console.log(results);
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
```